# Cant import socket module

Tags: sockets, python-2.7, module

i've written the following script on PyCharm IDE:

```
import socket
import time

sock = socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

hexpacket "00 FF"

ip = raw_input('Target IP: ')
port = input('Port: ')
duration = ('Number of seconds to send packets: ')
timeout = time.time() + duration
sent = 0

while True:
    if time.time() > timeout:
        break
    else:
        pass
    sock.sendto(hexpacket,(ip,port))
    sent = sent +1
    print "Send %s packet to %s through ports %s"(send, ip, port)
```

I get an output from the console of:

```
  TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I have tried to change the "import socket" statement to either "from socket import socket" and "from socket import *" but both did not help.

I also tried to use "pip install socket" but I get "could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement socket".

Any idea how do I solve this simple issue? I thought socket is a basic module that comes with every python download.

Thanks for the answers..!

Comment: Could you try `import socket` and then `sock=socket.socket(…)`?

Comment: Do you have a script named `socket.py`?

Comment: Nope. no script named socket.py

Comment: Fredtantini, thank you. I fixed it as you said and it now works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sock = socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
```

you are using socket **object** directly it's wrong it's throwing an error 
`TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`

Try this::

```
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
```